# Change tile URL in OpenLayers-3

Tags: openlayers

I am trying to change my tile URL in OpenLayers-3.

I made this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zoutepopcorn/hGynK/), with the code:

```
var map;
var icons = [];

var source = new ol.source.OSM();
map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({source: source}),
    new ol.layer.Vector({      
        source: new ol.source.Vector({features:icons})
    })],
    renderer: "canvas",
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View2D({
        zoom: 11
    })
});

// Change map source URL dynamically
// This line gives error in console:
// Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html:
source.setUrl('http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/');

map.getView().setCenter(transform(5, 52));

function transform(lng, lat) {
    return ol.proj.transform([lng, lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
}
```

The code breaks on the line:

```
source.setUrl('http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/');
```

It gives a message in the console (Chrome: Ctrl + shift + j):

```
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html:
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 4):

Solved the problem, I had tu use `ol.source.XYZ` instead of `ol.source.OSM()`

And later you can change map url by: `source.setUrl();`

```
ol.source.OSM();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zoutepopcorn/LwrrY/)

Source:
HTML:

```
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var map;
var icons = [];

var source = new ol.source.XYZ({
    url: 'http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png' });
map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({source: source}),
    new ol.layer.Vector({      
        source: new ol.source.Vector({features:icons})
    })],
    renderer: "canvas",
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View2D({
        zoom: 11
    })
});

// Change to other xyz url..
source.setUrl('http://otile1.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg');

map.getView().setCenter(transform(5, 52));
mapOffline();
function transform(lng, lat) {
    return ol.proj.transform([lng, lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
}

function mapOffline() {
    map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({source: source}),
    new ol.layer.Vector({      
        source: new ol.source.Vector({features:icons})
    })],
    renderer: "canvas",
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View2D({
        zoom: 11
    })
});

}
```